# when use phpwhois in cakephp show me Error: Class 'phpWhois\WhoisClient' not found

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I downloaded `phpwhois` from [here](https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois),
and copied it in vendor folder in `cakephp`.

But when I load `whois` class in controller :

```
App::import('Vendor', 'phpWhois\Whois', array('file' => 'phpWhois/Whois.php'));
```

It shows me this error :

> Error: Class 'phpWhois\WhoisClient' not found
>   File: \app\Vendor\phpWhois\Whois.php

Since `whois` class extend `WhoisClient`. 
What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried installing it with Composer and using autoload?

Answer (score 0):

install using following composer command

> php composer.phar require "phpwhois/phpwhois":"~4.0"

Add following line in bootstrap.php

> require APP . 'Vendor/autoload.php';
>
> spl_autoload_unregister(array('App', 'load'));
>
> spl_autoload_register(array('App', 'load'), true, true);

and add this before before controller's class definition

> use phpWhois\Whois;